# New to Blender and need advice

Tags: workflow

I'm a beginner on Blender and I start by following Andrew Price's tutorials, including the series on his YouTube channel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPrnSACiTJ4. The file generated after the first video weighs 720 KB, while after the fourth video we are already at 570 MB. In this part, some modifiers had to be added and applied. Hence the question: is it normal that the file becomes so large? I'm afraid that after all the videos of this training we'll end up with a huge file that would make navigation and handling much less fluid. Do you think my desktop configuration is insufficient? I use an Intel i5-7400 processor with 8 GB of RAM, without a graphics card. Should I plan to purchase a graphics card?
Thank you for all the advice provided.

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic for [blender.se], you may want to ask at https://blender.chat

Comment: It's normal that files become larger with complexity, especially if you apply modifiers like subsurface which increase the number of vertices. I can't tell if the increase in file size is normal for the tutorial you've been following. A GPU can be useful for speeding up rendering, however your RAM will likely be the bottleneck once you reach a certain complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked back at the files I saved at the end of each video (under Windows 7 using Blender 2.80 final):
Level 1
Part 2 around 607KB
Part 3 around 678KB
Part 4 around 679KB
Part 5 around 10,210KB
so there's a jump during part 4 of Level 1, but nothing like you report and in fact the final Level 4 file is under 14,000KB so you've done something wrong somewhere!
I'd be inclined to start again from the video before you see the jump in file size.
Your hardware shouldn't make any difference to the .blend file sizes.